# Make with Subdirectories gives "No rule to make target..."

Tags: gnu-make

As a part of a larger makefile, I make a .h file from a .hh file using config.txt and a perl script. The .hh files are in the /source directory and the resulting .h file goes into the /hdr directory. In this case semaphore.hh is in the source directory and the hdr directory exists and does not contain a semaphore.h file. The following makefile…

```
/hdr/semaphore.h : /source/semaphore.hh config.txt
#...
%.h: %.hh config.txt
<tab> perl copymod.pl $< >$@
```

…produces, “No rule to make target `/source/semaphore.hh', needed by` /hdr/semaphore.h'.”
How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

A pattern rule:

```
%.h: %.hh config.txt
```

is a *template* that tells make, "if you want to build a target that matches the pattern `%.h`, *and* if you can find or find a way to build the prerequisites `%.hh` and `config.txt`, then you can use this recipe to build the target".

In your case the file `/hdr/semaphore.h` matches the pattern `%.h` with a stem (the part that matches the `%`) of `/hdr/semaphore`.  So make substitutes that stem for the pattern in the prerequisite `%.hh` and comes up with `/hdr/semaphore.hh`.  So make will try to build that, but it can't and so you get the error you see.

If you want your `.h` and `.hh` files to be in different directories then the pattern has to reflect that.  For example you could write:

```
/hdr/%.h: /src/%.hh config.txt
```

and now for `/hdr/semaphore.h` the stem is `semaphore` and when you substitute that into `/src/%.hh` you get `/src/semaphore.hh`.

Comment: I guessed and it worked without a leading slash mark on both /hdr and /src

Comment: I don't understand your comment but simply removing the initial slash won't help in your original makefile _unless_ you have `semaphore.hh` in the `hdr` directory.  In your question you implied that the `semaphore.hh` file was in the `source` directory not the `hdr` directory.